# Regex to match content inside HTML element

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a Regex in c# to match "get title" in a Header element:

```
<h2>\r\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/photo/123\">get title</a>\r\n</h2>
```

I only want to get content inside `<h2>` element.

I tried to use this:

```
Regex _title = new Regex("<a (.+?)>");
```

But it isn't working, please help.

Comment: `Regex _r = new Regex("<a .+?>(.*?)</a>");`

Comment: I want get only content inside h2,because <a (.+?)> will get context unnecessary

Comment: structure i want get is title inside h2,

Comment: "it is working" isn't very helpful.  Please describe how it isn't working.

Comment: when I get content,have a lot of a target href, but header inside H2, i use <a .+?>(.*?)</a> will get unnecessary content

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
string baseText = "<h2>\r\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/photo/123\">get title</a>\r\n</h2>";
Regex _title = new Regex("<a .+?>(?<title>.*?)</a>");
Match match = _title.Match(baseText);

string title = match.Groups["title"].Value;
```

Hope it suits your needs.

**Update:**
Change the `Regex` like this:

```
Regex _title = new Regex("<h2>(\r\n*)<a .+?>(?<title>.*?)</a>(\r\n*)</h2>");
```

I made the linebreaks between `<h2>` and `<a>` tags optional.

Comment: It get outside H2  and Inside H2, i try get only header inside H2 but   it isn't working

Comment: @tranthanhthanh have you tried the updated answer? Give me some feedback whether you need further assistance.

Comment: It working with header text, but header have feel icon and text notworking <pre><h2>\r\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/photo/93846\">text title <img class='emo' src='http://abc/content/images/emo/static/laugh.png' /></a>\r\n</h2></pre>

Comment: Tried it and its working as expected. You get the complete content of <a>-tag. What is it what is not working? What would be the correct result for you?

Comment: Regex _title = new Regex(@"<a .+?>(?<title>.*?)<img.*?/></a>");

Comment: @tranthanhthanh If my answer helped you out please mark it as accepted. If not let us know what is missing.